# How to map a route for /News/5 to my news controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to identify how to map a route for /News/5 to my news controller.

This is my NewsController:

```
public class NewsController : BaseController
{
    //
    // GET: /News

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

This is my Global.asax.cs rule:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "News", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "News", action = "Index", id = -1 } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I try to go to /News/5 but I receive a resource not found error, however when going to /News/Index/5 it works?

I have tried just `{controller}/{id}` but that just produced the same issue.

Thanks!

Comment: When you tried `{controller}/{id}` did you keep action in the defaults? `new { controller = "News", action = "Index", id = -1 }`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `{controller}/{id}` route was correct but you problaby registered it AFTER the other route. In the route list it searches top down and the first match it finds wins.

To help steer routing I would suggest creating route constraints for this to ensure that #1 the controller exists and #2 the `{id}` is a number.

See [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs)

Mainly:

```
 routes.MapRoute( 
        "Index Action", // Route name 
        "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters EDIT: forgot starting "
        new { controller = "News", action = "Index" },
        new {id= @"\d+" }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I cannot accept your message for 8 minutes but I will return. You fixed my issue with the constraints: `new { controller = "News", id = @"0|-?[1-9]\d*" } // Route constraints` and moving it above the other map route

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure your new route is before your default route, like so:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "NewsAbbr", // Route name
        "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "News", action = "Index", id = -1 } // Parameter defaults
    );


    routes.MapRoute(
        "News", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "News", action = "Index", id = -1 } // Parameter defaults
    );
```